# Integrating Bitbucket with IntelliJ Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, bitbucket

Trying to integrate IntelliJ Idea and Bitbucket repo. Basically I've enabled version control in VCS option and download Bitbucket Linky plugin. Bitbucket is already set up-all rights and permissions are okay and Bitbucket is successfully integrated with SourceTree (all the operations like cloning, pulling/pushing are available).

But the thing is that when I'm entered IntelliJ Idea and from the startup screen try to check out from Version Control system and then select "Git" in the options and try to connect one of the repos, it appears to be an error "Clone Failed. Could not read from remote repository".

So what am I doing wrong in this case and how it can be solved to successfully match Bitbucket with Idea?

Really looking forward for your ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SSH to access BitBucket, then most likely there are some issues with the SSH-key/client configuration. See e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase

Comment: Basically, using command "ssh-add -K " and turn SSH to "Native" does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It’s unnecessary to download bitbucket plugin, you just need to **input credential for the bitbucket repo to clone**.

The way to clone a bitbucket repo in IntelliJ Idea usually as below:

Checkout from version control -> Git -> Bitbucket repo URL -> Test -> make sure the connection is successful -> Clone.

[image]

If the test connection is failed, you should make sure the password you entered is correct. You can set as below steps in order to enter the password again:

In the startup page -> configure -> settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Passwords -> select Don not save, forget passwords after restart -> Ok -> close and restart IntelliJ Idea.

[image]

Then you can checkout bitbucket repo again to test the connection:

Checkout from version control -> Git -> Bitbucket repo URL -> Test -> Then it will ask you for the password -> input the password -> after the connection is successful -> clone the repo.

[image]